# How do I know if hardware acceleration of the GPU is enabled in VLC?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, gpu, codec, acceleration

Under the new VLC interface (Linux) with video-Catalyst driver installed what option I can chose to enable GPU hardware acceleration?

How can I be sure it is enabled?

[image]

---

$ `vainfo` give me this output :

```
 libva info: VA-API version 0.37.0
 libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
 libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_drv_video.so
 libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_33
 libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
 vainfo: VA-API version: 0.37 (libva 1.5.0)
 vainfo: Driver version: AMD MMD 1.0
 vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
 VAProfileH264Baseline           :  VAEntrypointVLD
 VAProfileH264Main               :  VAEntrypointVLD
 VAProfileH264High               :  VAEntrypointVLD
 VAProfileVC1Simple              :  VAEntrypointVLD
 VAProfileVC1Main                :  VAEntrypointVLD
 VAProfileVC1Advanced            :  VAEntrypointVLD
```

Running $ `vlc --ffmpeg-hw -v` print :

```
VLC media player 2.2.0 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-0-g1349ef2)
[09af99e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/control/liblirc_plugin.so' (liblirc_client.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[09af99e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libtwolame_plugin.so' (libtwolame.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[09af99e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/visualization/libprojectm_plugin.so' (libprojectM.so.2: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[09af99e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/visualization/libgoom_plugin.so' (libgoom2.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[09af99e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access/libvcdx_plugin.so' (libvcdinfo.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
Warning: option --ffmpeg-hw no longer exists.
[09af99e0] core libvlc: Lancement de vlc avec l'interface par défaut. Utilisez « cvlc » pour démarrer VLC sans interface.
```

And running $ `cvlc --ffmpeg-hw -v` print :

```
VLC media player 2.2.0 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-0-g1349ef2)
[09a9c9e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/control/liblirc_plugin.so' (liblirc_client.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[09a9c9e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libtwolame_plugin.so' (libtwolame.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[09a9c9e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/visualization/libprojectm_plugin.so' (libprojectM.so.2: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[09a9c9e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/visualization/libgoom_plugin.so' (libgoom2.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[09a9c9e0] core libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/access/libvcdx_plugin.so' (libvcdinfo.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
Warning: option --ffmpeg-hw no longer exists.
[09b6d530] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
```

Same output with $ `vlc --avcodec-hw -v` !

Answer (score 1):

If catalyst is installed and configured properly, `vainfo` should give an output like this

```
 libva: libva version 0.32.0
 Xlib:  extension "XFree86-DRI" missing on display ":0.0".
 libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
 libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_drv_video.so
 libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
 vainfo: VA API version: 0.32
 vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems XvBA backend for VA-API - 0.7.8
 vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
 VAProfileH264High               :  VAEntrypointVLD
 VAProfileVC1Advanced            :  VAEntrypointVLD
```

And running

```
vlc --ffmpeg-hw -v
```

Should print a line like

```
[0x7fd018c02d38] avcodec decoder: Using VA API version 0.32 for hardware decoding.
```